# Chevron toggle on whole link area

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Does anyone know how to adjust this jQuery script for the chevron swap to work on the whole "a" tag area? At the moment it just works on the chevron itself:

```
$('.chevron_toggleable').on('click', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3u8pj62/1/

Thanks

Oli

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.kb-nav-affix').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.chevron_toggleable').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
});
```

The above is the updated javascript. It should fix your issue.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for. Thanks.